# Perl thread library deadlock

Tags: multithreading, class, perl

I created a thread manager class in Perl as follows:

```
package ThreadManager;

use threads;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new{
    my ($class,$nbThreads) = @_;

    if (!defined($nbThreads) || $nbThreads <= 0) {
        $nbThreads=1;
    }
    my @threadStatus = (1) x $nbThreads;
    my @threadHdl = (0) x $nbThreads;

    my $self = bless {
                      nbThreads => $nbThreads,
                      threadStatus => [ @threadStatus ],
                      threadHdl => [ @threadHdl ],
                      nextAvailableThread => 0
                     }, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub launchThread {
    my ($self,$childProcess, @args) = @_;

    while (1) {

        ### looking if thread is used, running, or has completed
        if (!$self->{threadStatus}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}] && !$self->{threadHdl}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}]->is_running) {
            $self->{threadHdl}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}]->join();
            $self->{threadStatus}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}] = 1;
        }

        ### if thread from thread are available, lauch the process
        if ($self->{threadStatus}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}]) {
            $self->{threadHdl}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}] =
                threads->create( \&$childProcess, @args );
            $self->{threadStatus}[$self->{nextAvailableThread}] = 0;
            last;
        }

        $self->{nextAvailableThread}++;
        if ($self->{nextAvailableThread} == $self->{nbThreads}) {
            $self->{nextAvailableThread} = 0;
            ### sleep so not to overload the system with thread checks
            sleep 1;
        }
    }

    ############ Setting start point for next available thread search
    $self->{nextAvailableThread} = ($self->{nextAvailableThread} == ($self->{nbThreads} - 1))? 0: $self->{nextAvailableThread} + 1;
}


sub waitThreadCompletion {
    my ($self) = @_;
    ### Waiting for all threads to complete
    for my $thrd (0 .. $#{$self->{threadStatus}}) {
        if (!$self->{threadStatus}[$thrd]) {
            $self->{threadHdl}[$thrd]->join();
            $self->{threadStatus}[$thrd] = 1;
         }
    }
}

1;
```

I know that there is a thread::pool package available but the above code works and I wanted to create an class that can be reuse in my code to handle the allocation of available threads. I could probably use an existing package for this but I'm really curious why this is not working as expected.

I create a small test program that uses the above class:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use ThreadManager;


sub Log {print @_, "\n"; $|=1}

my $nbThreads = 3;

my $threadHdl = ThreadManager->new($nbThreads);

my @fetchedRows = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
                  51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60);

my @fetchedColumns = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

sub internalProcessing{
   my $ComponentId = shift;
   my $DeviceId = shift;
   my $ColumnId = shift;
   my $sleepTime = ($ComponentId % 3) + 1;
   Log("START -> INSIDE INTERNAL THREAD -> Devices [$DeviceId] Column [$ColumnId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);
   Log("  RUN -> INSIDE INTERNAL THREAD -> Devices [$DeviceId] Column [$ColumnId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] sleep [$sleepTime seconds]");
   sleep $sleepTime;

   Log("  END -> INSIDE INTERNAL THREAD -> Devices [$DeviceId] Column [$ColumnId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);

   threads->exit();
}
sub processing {
   my $ComponentId = shift;
   my $DeviceId = shift;
   my $sleepTime = ($ComponentId % 3) + 1;
   Log("START -> INSIDE THREAD -> Discovery Started for Devices [$DeviceId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);
   Log("  RUN -> INSIDE THREAD -> Sleeping for $sleepTime seconds");
   sleep $sleepTime;
   my $interThreadHdl = ThreadManager->new(4);
   for ( @fetchedColumns ) {
      my $Columns = $_;
      Log("[$threadId:$$] -> LAUCH SUB THREAD INIT -> Discovery Started for Devices [$DeviceId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);
      $interThreadHdl->launchThread(\&internalProcessing, $ComponentId, $DeviceId, $Columns);
      Log("[$threadId:$$] -> LAUCH SUB THREAD COMPLETED -> Discovery Started for Devices [$DeviceId] ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);
   }
   $interThreadHdl->waitThreadCompletion();

   Log("  END[$threadId:$$] -> INSIDE THREAD -> Discovery completed for Devices [$DeviceId]  ComponentID [$ComponentId] on thread " . threads->self);

   threads->exit();
}
my $idx=1;
for ( @fetchedRows ) {
    my $Row = $_;
    my $DeviceId = "device#$Row";

    Log("Discovery Started for Device [$DeviceId]");
    my $ComponentId = $idx;
    $idx++;

    $threadHdl->launchThread(\&processing, $ComponentId, $DeviceId);
}

$threadHdl->waitThreadCompletion();


Log("Done");
```

However, every once in a while the thread share library code seems to go into a dealock. I traced the library code and it seems to get stuck on the following call in threads.c which is part of the threads.so shared library (the specific call is perl_clone in the S_ithread_create function, I'm running this on Linux):

```
#ifdef WIN32
    thread->interp = perl_clone(aTHX, CLONEf_KEEP_PTR_TABLE | CLONEf_CLONE_HOST);
#else
    thread->interp = perl_clone(aTHX, CLONEf_KEEP_PTR_TABLE);
#endif

    /* perl_clone() leaves us in new interpreter's context.  As it is tricky
     * to spot an implicit aTHX, create a new scope with aTHX matching the
     * context for the duration of our work for new interpreter.
     */
```

The deadlock does not seems to happen every time but when it does everything stops, or, the waitThreadCompletion or launchThread functions loops indefinetly as the threads are not tagged as completed by the threads library. I'm not under the impression that the issue is in my perl code as it is relatively simple but if anyone has any pointers on this, it would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully, this is not a bug in the threads library but in my code.

I ran the above program with the class code within the program instead of using a class and it works fine. I'm suspecting that I'm doing something wrong in my class definition or that there is a bug with the threads library when it is used within a class.

Comment: One thing I notice right away is your `while(1)` loop will block when waiting for a thread to open, you should probably use a queue data structure to handle the creation of threads, running on its own thread, to not block the execution of the program.

Comment: Correct but this is not the issue. The fact that the program goes into a wait state is not due to the while loop but due to a deadlock that occurs within the C code itself. I added traces within the perl thread library and I saw the deadlock occur.